# Can Xcode SDKs (such as watchOS and tvOS) be uninstalled?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have installed Xcode in my machine in order to use it for desktop development (OS X/Cocoa/Command line tools). Whenever I create a new project, there are templates in the wizard for iOS, watchOS and tvOS development, but at this moment I have no interest in these SDKs.

Since Xcode.app is taking a lot of space in my disk even after a fresh install, is it possible to remove these SDKs and reclaim some space?

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to do this. I don't know at this moment if this can have any side-effect on other components for Xcode that could fail. In that case it may be possible to reinstall it from the Mac AppStore again.

Xcode packages the SDKs for these different products as Platforms. There is a Platform for macOS, a Platform for iOS, and so on. All these Platforms are stored in this folder:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms
```

It seems it's possible to actually remove platforms by deleting the correspondent folders inside, such as:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform
```

Whenever one or more of these folders are deleted, the New Project wizard won't even show them anymore as categories.

[image: New Project wizard]

Comment: Above in incorrect. You will have to reinstall Xcode if you delete any of these folders.


/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform


I deleted above Xcode wanted me to reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Above in incorrect. You will have to reinstall Xcode if you delete any of these folders. /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform I deleted above Xcode wanted me to reinstall.

Try to delete all folders besides "developer" inside platform folders.
Example, delete all beside this:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/developer.
Other folders in that area you can delete

Comment: This is the right answer. Deleting .platform folders will break Xcode.

Comment: I am afraid, it's POSSIBLE to delete unwanted platforms and still run Xcode without encountering any crash. I have retained only the following folders inside my Platforms directory and deleted the rest (especially, the leviathan tvOS platform) manually.
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel   224B Sep 18 18:42 DriverKit.platform
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160B Sep 18 18:42 MacOSX.platform
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel   352B Oct  7 03:28 iPhoneOS.platform
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel   256B Oct  7 02:36 iPhoneSimulator.platform

Comment: I deleted TVOS stuff and was still able to build my iPhone app (but not clean build so I could be wrong).